# How to make discord.js bot repeat message given to it in another channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js and am trying to make a bot so that everytime this specific person says something from another server that the bot is in, I want the bot to repeat this message in a specific channel.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author === ("244921929495085057")){
    client.channels.get("655598459268759593").send(message.content);
  }
})
```

I can't figure out how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: What happens/doesn't happen with the code you provided? What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: @slothiful nothing currently happens. As for the version, I'm not sure. I'm quite inexperienced and am just using node.js to run a file called bot.js hosted by heroku.

Comment: For the future, use `npm ls discord.js` to find out what version of the package are you using.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using the latest version of discord.js which is v12 at the time of writing this.

According to the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=cache)

You need to add `.cache` after `client.channels` to access the channels list.